# c++ - Linked List - program break when i use -> in print function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote a linked list and everything works fine but when I tried to use a particular function and print it I get an error I will be happy to help Why do I get an error and how to fix it.

The error occurs only when I call the ReverseNew-> print ();

function reverseList(in main.cpp):

```
List * reverseList(List &listToReverse){

List newList;
Node* currentPtr = listToReverse.getFirstNode();

while (currentPtr != 0){
    newList.AddElement(currentPtr->getdata());
    currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
}

Node* currentNode = newList.getFirstNode();
int size = newList.size();
while (currentNode != 0){
    currentNode->setId(size);
    size--;
    currentNode = currentNode->getNextPtr();
}
return &newList;
}
```

main:

```
int main(){

List l1;
l1.AddElement(1);
l1.AddElement(2);
l1.AddElement(3);
**l1.print(); >> Here he prints the list and works fine**

List* reverseNew = reverseList(l1);
**reverseNew->print(); >> here the program break** 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

print function: (in List.cpp)

```
void List::print(){
Node* currentNode = firstPtr;

if (isEmpty())
    std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;
else{
    while (currentNode != 0){
        std::cout << " < " << currentNode->data << " , " << currentNode->ID 
<< " > " << std::endl;
        currentNode = currentNode->nextPtr;
    }}}
```

When the program comes out she takes me to this line: (in print function)

```
std::cout << " < " << currentNode->data << " , " << currentNode->ID 
<< " > " << std::endl;
```

thabk's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **reverseList(List &listToReverse)** function body, you create a variable **newList** which goes out of scope and gets destroyed after the function ends its execution. When you try to reference that variable later in your code, that causes undefined behaviour, because you try to reference something that had already been deleted. Make **newList** a pointer instead to fix this (or, better, a **smart pointer**).

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove part of the function it should be easier to see the issue:

```
List * reverseList(List &listToReverse){

    List newList;
    // ...
    return &newList;
}
```

You return the address of a local variable. It's an Undefined Behaviour (UB).
To fix this you have two solution: return a copy of the object (beware of shallow copy issues), or use dynamic allocation in the function (check out the standard library smart pointer  `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr`)